# Hash or List-Backed Levels of a Factor

Tags: r

I'm dealing with a categorical variable retrieved from a database and am wanting to use factors to maintain the "fullness" of the data.

For instance, I have a table which stores colors and their associated numerical ID

```
  ID  | Color
------+-------
    1 | Black
 1805 | Red
 3704 | White
```

So I'd like to use a factor to store this information in a data frame such as:

```
Car Model | Color
----------+-------
Civic     | Black
Accord    | White
Sentra    | Red
```

where the color column is a factor and the underlying data stored, rather than being a string, is actually c(1, 3704, 1805) -- to IDs associated with each color.

So I can create a custom factor by modifying the levels attribute of an object of the factor class to achieve this effect.

Unfortunately, as you can see in the example, my IDs are not incremented. In my application, I have ~30 levels and the maximum ID for one level is ~9,000. Because the levels are stored in an array for a factor, that means I'm storing an integer vector of length 9,000 with only 30 elements in it.

Is there any way to use a hash or list to accomplish this effect more efficiently? i.e. if I were to use a hash in the levels attribute of a factor, I could store all 30 elements with whatever indices I please without having to create an array of size max(ID).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I'm pretty sure you can't change how factors work. A factor always has level ids that are integer numbers `1..n` where `n` is the number of levels.

...but you can easily have a translation vector to get to your color ids:

```
# The translation vector...
colorIds <- c(Black=1,Red=1805,White=3704)

# Create a factor with the correct levels 
# (but with level ids that are 1,2,3...)
f <- factor(c('Red','Black','Red','White'), levels=names(colorIds))
as.integer(f) # 2 1 2 3

# Translate level ids to your color ids
colorIds[f] # 1805 1 1805 3704
```

Technically, `colorIds` does not need to define the names of the colors, but it makes it easier to have in one place since the names are used when creating the levels for the factor. You want to specify the levels explicitly so that the numbering of them matches even if the levels are not in alphabetical order (as yours happen to be).

**EDIT** It is however possible to create a class deriving from factor that has the codes as an attribute. Lets call this new glorious class `foo`:

```
foo <- function(x = character(), levels, codes) {
    f <- factor(x, levels)
    attr(f, 'codes') <- codes
    class(f) <- c('foo', class(f))
    f
}

`[.foo` <- function(x, ...) {
    y <- NextMethod('[')
    attr(y, 'codes') <- attr(x, 'codes')
    y
}

as.integer.foo <- function(x, ...) attr(x,'codes')[unclass(x)]

# Try it out
set.seed(42)
f <- foo(sample(LETTERS[1:5], 10, replace=TRUE), levels=LETTERS[1:5], codes=101:105)

d <- data.frame(i=11:15, f=f)

# Try subsetting it...
d2 <- d[2:5,]

# Gets the codes, not the level ids...
as.integer(d2$f) # 105 102 105 104
```

You could then also fix `print.foo` etc...

Comment: Thanks, Tommy. I'm hoping for something that would avoid having to do a second step (of looking up the actual ID), but what you suggested may end up being as good as it gets.

Comment: This solutions seems a bit less elegant to me than the other hash-based answer (though probably easier to work with), but -- surprisingly -- I'm getting better performance with this code than I was using the hash. It looks like, though constant, the time to retrieve an element from a hashed environment is long enough that your array-based code performs better when the number of levels is < ~4000 (hash takes a constant .25s to format a 10,000 row df, yours takes .17 + .0000212L where L is the number of levels).

Comment: So I'll lay aside my theoretical algorithm analysis and use this one! The only downside is the overhead to store the codes in a separate data structure, but assuming that the number of values >> the number of levels, that's likely not a concern.

Answer (score 0):

In thinking about it, the only feature that a "level" needs to implement in order to have a valid factor is the `[` accessor. So any object implementing the `[` accessor could be viewed as a vector from the standpoint of any interfacing function.

I looked into the [hash](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/hash/index.html) class, but saw that it uses the normal R behavior (as is seen in lists) of returning a slice of the original hash when only using a single bracket (while extracting the actual value when using the double bracket). However, it I were to override this using setMethod(), I was actually able to get the desired behavior.

```
library(hash)

setMethod( 
    '[' , 
    signature( x="hash", i="ANY", j="missing", drop = "missing") ,  
    function( 
        x,i,j, ... ,        
        drop
        ) {     

        if (class(i) == "factor"){
            #presumably trying to lookup the values associated with the ordered keys in this hash
            toReturn <- NULL
            for (k in make.keys(as.integer(i))){
                toReturn <- c(toReturn, get(k, envir=x@.xData))
            }
            return(toReturn)
        }

        #default, just make keys and get from the environment
        toReturn <- NULL
        for (k in make.keys(i)){
            toReturn <- c(toReturn, get(k, envir=x@.xData))
        }
        return(toReturn)        
    }
    )

as.character.hash <- function(h){
    as.character(values(h))
}

print.hash <- function(h){
    print(as.character(h))
}

h <- hash(1:26, letters)

df <- data.frame(ID=1:26, letter=26:1, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

attributes(df$letter)$class <- "factor"
attributes(df$letter)$levels <- h

>   df
   ID letter
1   1      z
2   2      y
3   3      x
4   4      w
5   5      v
6   6      u
7   7      t
8   8      s
9   9      r
10 10      q
11 11      p
12 12      o
13 13      n
14 14      m
15 15      l
16 16      k
17 17      j
18 18      i
19 19      h
20 20      g
21 21      f
22 22      e
23 23      d
24 24      c
25 25      b
26 26      a
>   attributes(df$letter)$levels
<hash> containing 26 key-value pair(s).
  1 : a
  10 : j
  11 : k
  12 : l
  13 : m
  14 : n
  15 : o
  16 : p
  17 : q
  18 : r
  19 : s
  2 : b
  20 : t
  21 : u
  22 : v
  23 : w
  24 : x
  25 : y
  26 : z
  3 : c
  4 : d
  5 : e
  6 : f
  7 : g
  8 : h
  9 : i
>
> df[1,2]
[1] z
Levels: a j k l m n o p q r s b t u v w x y z c d e f g h i
> as.integer(df$letter)
 [1] 26 25 24 23 22 21 20 19 18 17 16 15 14 13 12 11 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2
[26]  1
```

Any feedback on this? As best I can tell, everything's working. It looks like it works properly as far as printing, and the underlying data stored in the actual data.frame is untouched, so I don't feel like I'm jeopardizing anything there. I may even be able to get away with adding a new class into my package which just implements this accessor to avoid having to add a dependency on the hash class.

Any feedback or points on what I'm overlooking would be much appreciated.