# String-transform vector-elements in data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a huge data frame `df`, with in one column a 'year-month' value as follows: "YYYYMM". Currently the data type is a number. Snapshot:

```
> df[[1]][1:10]
[1] 201001 201001 201001 201001 201001 201001 201001 201001 201001 201001
> str(df)
'data.frame':   2982393 obs. of  11 variables:
 $ YearMonth    : int  201001 201001 201001 201001 201001 201001 201001 201001 201001 201001 ...
 $ ...
```

What I want is to transform this value to a string (eventually to a factor) in the form "YYYY-MM", to be able to compare this with other data frames.

I'm struggling to find an easy way to transform the value.

I tried using `as.Date` and the `format` function. But as the values do not have any days, it didn't work for Strings. With Numerics (same with dataframe column) I even got other problems.

```
> as.Date("201001", format = "%Y%m")
 [1] NA

> as.Date(201001, format = "%Y%m")
 Error in as.Date.numeric(201001, format = "%Y%m") : 
    'origin' must be supplied
> as.Date(df[[1]], format = "%Y%m")
 Error in as.Date.numeric(df[[1]], format = "%Y%m") : 
    'origin' must be supplied
```

I'm able to transform just one value, using `subset` and concatenation of strings. 
I wrote the formula below, to handle one element:

```
transformString <- function( x ) { # x = value
    return ( paste(cbind(substring(x, 1, 4),"-",substring(x,5,6)), collapse = '') )
}
```

Problem: I didn't find an easy way to apply that function to a whole column of an data.frame, other than just traversing all elements:

```
transformStringVector <- function( x ) { # x = vector
    for(i in 1:length(x)) {
       x[i]<-transformString(x[i])
    }
    return ( x )
}
```

This is far from elegant and bad for performance. I tried to use `apply` (see below) and stuff like that, but was confronted with errors... (I admit I do not really get the `apply` function)

```
> temp <- apply(df[[1]], 1, transformString )
Error in apply(df[[1]], 1, transformString ) : 
  dim(X) must have a positive length
```

Does anybody have an alternative for this transformation within a huge data.frame? Or more in general; an easy way to apply string-like-transformations to elements within a data.frame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question about applying this to a data.frame specifically, you could access the column using the `$` operator. So you could use either of the functions offered here (I would have gone with the substr variant) to do it. If you're planning to convert to a factor, I'd do that first.

```
> df <- data.frame(a=1:5,b=5:1,d=200101:200105)
> df
  a b      d
1 1 5 200101
2 2 4 200102
3 3 3 200103
4 4 2 200104
5 5 1 200105
> #Convert to a factor now for performance reasons.
> df$d <- as.factor(df$d)
> df$d <- paste(substr(df$d, 1, 4), "-", substr(df$d, 5,6), sep="")
> df
  a b       d
1 1 5 2001-01
2 2 4 2001-02
3 3 3 2001-03
4 4 2 2001-04
5 5 1 2001-05

> typeof(df$d)
[1] "character"
> df$d <- as.factor(df$d)
> df
  a b       d
1 1 5 2001-01
2 2 4 2001-02
3 3 3 2001-03
4 4 2 2001-04
5 5 1 2001-05
> typeof(df$d)
[1] "integer"
```

Note that depending on how "huge" your data.frame is, you might get better performance by converting to a factor first, then just converting the levels to hyphenated dates.

```
> df <- data.frame(a=rep(1:5,1000000),b=rep(5:1,1000000),d=rep(200101:200105, 1000000))
> nrow(df)
 [1] 5000000
> # Hyphenate first
> system.time(df$d <- paste(substr(df$d, 1, 4), "-", substr(df$d, 5,6), sep="")) + system.time(df$d <- as.factor(df$d))
  user  system elapsed 
  9.65    0.61   10.31 
>
> #Factor first
> system.time(df$d <- as.factor(df$d)) + system.time(levels(df$d) <- paste(substr(levels(df$d), 1, 4), "-", substr(levels(df$d), 5,6), sep=""))
 user  system elapsed 
 0.68    0.25    0.93
```

So, depending on the properties of your data.frame, you may be able to improve performance 10X by doing the factoring first.

P.S. If you *really* care about performance, you might be able to get better properties on your factoring code (the slowest part of the fast solution) by using a [hash-backed factor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9793317/hash-or-list-backed-levels-of-a-factor).

Comment: Nice! This is really helpful! This gives me some more insight into performance wrt factors. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The reason why

```
> as.Date("201001", format = "%Y%m")
 [1] NA
```

doesn't work, is that an R date needs a day component. Since your date doesn't provide one, you get a missing value. To circumvent this, just add a day component:

```
R> x = c("201001","201102")
R> x = paste(x, "01", sep="")
```

So I've made all the dates the first of the month:

```
R> y = as.Date(x, "%Y%m%d")
[1] "2010-01-01" "2011-02-01"
```

You can then use `format` to get what you want:

```
R> format(y, "%Y-%m")
[1] "2010-01" "2011-02"
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're just looking to transform the column values into a string in the specified format and don't care about having the `date` format, `substr()` and `paste()` both take vectors as arguments:

```
xx<-c(201011,201003,201002,201010,201009,201005,201001,201001,201001,201001)

paste(substr(xx,1,4),substr(xx,5,6),sep="-")
# [1] "2010-11" "2010-03" "2010-02" "2010-10" "2010-09" "2010-05" "2010-01"
# [8] "2010-01" "2010-01" "2010-01"
```

In this way, you don't have to use `apply()`